# Verbs without any infinitive form

Tags: verbs

Does anyone know why verbs like "come" and "go" don't take, optionally, a connector or to-infinitive form. For instance:

> 1.- Go: Darling!, **go** (and) see who's knocking on the door!
>
> 2.- Come: **Come** (and) see this girl. She is gorgeus!

Are there any other verbs which obey this structure?

Comment: You may want to read about [imperative mood](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood).

Comment: This is almost exclusively an American English trait. The only expression in this form that is widely used in the UK is "go figure". It probably doesn't involve infinitives: it's actually two imperatives. If it were an infinitive, it would be "go to see".

Comment: @JavaLatte has it exactly right. With *come VERB* or *go VERB*, *go* an *come* never take explicit subjects and never inflect for tense or person. The two imperatives are 'conjoined' with a null conjunction; in fact, you also encounter *come and VERB* and *go and VERB* in the same sense.

Answer (score 1):

As **@LucianSava** commented this is the imperative mood.

> The **'imperative mood'** is a grammatical mood that forms commands or requests, including the giving of prohibition or permission, or any other kind of advice or exhortation.

In this grammatical mood we can position two verb with a null conjunction **(and)**, however, we can include the conjunction and the meaning will not change. Most sources say that the **null conjunction** is mostly relevant in the US while the conjunction **and** is relevant in the UK. Saying something like *“Go make me a drink”* is distinctive as part of American English in particular.

- Go (and) take this book to Mom.
- I'll go (and) bring myself a glass of water.
- Come (and) sit beside me.

**Come** and **Go** can both take *a bare infinitive* that's why such constructions are possible.

There's an interesting moment about stacking verbs in the imperative mood, see here: [Should I always insert **“and”** between two verbs in the imperative mood?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85155/should-i-always-insert-and-between-two-verbs-in-imperative-mode)